# Javascript how to append all class list to innerHTML then apply it on the webpage

Tags: javascript

I want to remove all the elements in the page except for the elements that I want. I am using chrome inspect element console.

So I am thinking of this method:

document.body.innerHTML = texts.innerHTML;

I tried the code below but it only appends the 1st element of texts to body.innerHTML.

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('HoXoMd D1wxyf G4EHhc');
for(let text of texts){
    document.body.innerHTML = text.innerHTML;
}
```

I tried the code below, it does appends but did not change the website, it only appends on the console when u print it:

```
var texts = document.getElementsByClassName('HoXoMd D1wxyf G4EHhc');
for(let text of texts){
    document.body.innerHTML += text.innerHTML;
}
```

i am new to javascript thanks

Comment: The second example [does work](https://jsfiddle.net/hwxv9dn1/).

Comment: @Andy Thanks but i tried to run it on chrome console, the console and it only prints text on console but did not actually change the webpage.

Comment: If you need to "remove" existing and then use all elements from `"texts"`, then the second will not work for you, I think. It does `+=` -> so, it appends.

Comment: You've completely changed the context of your question. @JadeLaurenceC.Empleo.

Comment: sorry, it does append but how can i apply the output of the for loop to the webpage? It only appends on the console. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You second code snippet is fine, you are just missing one thing: you have to clear all the html after selecting the elements you want to keep, and then start adding them again to your DOM.

```js
// use querySelectorAll instead
var texts = document.querySelectorAll('.keep'); 

// clear all html
document.body.innerHTML = ''; // <- 

// add all the html you want back to the dom
for (const text of texts) 
  document.body.appendChild(text)
```

```html
<div class="keep">keep this</div>
<div>don't care about this</div>
<div>don't care about this</div>
<div class="keep">keep this too</div>
<div>don't care about this</div>
<div class="keep">keep this also</div>
```

you can change `.keep` with whatever class you want.

Comment: Thanks this works better because i can add <br>. thanks again :)

Comment: @JadeLaurenceC.Empleo Just don't use `innerHTML` to add the line-break = ).

Answer (score 2):

[`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) is rarely a good tool for modifying existing document. Also modifying document during iterating a live collection may produce unexpected results.

You can collect all the elements except the wanted, and then remove them from the document, like this:

```js
const texts = document.body.querySelectorAll('*:not(.HoXoMd.D1wxyf.G4EHhc)');
for (let text of texts) {
  text.remove();
}
```

```html
<p>Paragraph 1</p>
<p class="HoXoMd D1wxyf G4EHhc">Remains 1</p>
<p class="HoXoMd D1wxyf G4EHhc">Remains 2</p>
<p class="HoXoMd D1wxyf G4EHhc">Remains 3</p>
<p class="HoXoMd">Paragraph 2</p>
```

The universal `*` selector collects all the elements in `document.body`, `:not` pseudo-class excludes the elements matching the selector passed to `:not`. The NodeList [`element.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelector) returns is static, and you can remove elements in a loop without getting a mess a live list would cause.

It's notable, that using `element.querySelectorAll` is crucial, if you used `document.querySelectorAll`, all the elements in the document would be removed, including `head` and `body`, and nothing would be left on the page.

Comment: thanks it works but how can I add line break for each text? I tried this but did not work:

for (let text of texts) {
    text.remove();
    document.createElement("br")
}

Comment: @JadeLaurenceC.Empleo You've give an example of the elements. This is just an answer to your existing question: "_remove all the elements in the page except for the elements that I want_".